# Does this patent cover using social connections data to better the search results

Tags: us8055673

In reference to the patent: [US8055673](https://www.google.com/patents/US8055673)

Does this patent also cover the following :
a. Capturing additional key words based on the user's social connections data 
b. Giving an option to the user to give a list of friends/select his friends on the social network who he thinks might know the right answer or can support the search

Answer (score 0):

As you've stated things above, I'd say "no".

To point to only the first difference that seems obvious to me, all the independent claims specify "receiving [...] a timeline from the user". So, at the very least, the user would also have to provide a timeline as part of receiving the subject of the query.

The independent claims to talk about that timeline actually being *used* in the process of carrying out the query, but it still needs to be received.

It also requires:

> meta-learning logic executed by the processor for learning meta-data based on the search recommendation response from the search friend, the meta-learning logic using the meta-data to improve future search**es** performed by a meta-search algorithm;

[emphasis added]

That means the results from the friend can't just be used to generate results in one search--since it specifies "future searches", it clearly has to be used to produce results in at least two searches.